# How to setup a VPN using OPENVPN?

Tags: centos, vpn, openvpn

Hi I just bought a Virtual Private Server. My O/S is CentOS. I want to setup a VPN server using OpenVPN. How can I do it? I'm only given one ip address, can i setup with only 1 ip address?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this documentation :
http://www.howtoforge.com/openvpn-server-on-centos-5.2

Comment: I second this -- My company VPN uses this exact guide for our VPN, works like a charm.

I had to google a Win7 VPN client.

Comment: I think you could use the current OpenVPN client for windows on the official website. Unfortunatly, I don't know if it works on Windows 7 or not for the moment.